# How to pass a formik initialState value as a parameter to a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, formik

I am using Formik within my React app and unsure how to pass a Formik value prop as a parameter into a function.

Let's say that I have the following Formik values:

```
"props": {
    "myJobName": "ABC"
 }
```

Within my button tag which all lives within my `<Formik>` and `<Form>` tags, I am trying to call `setJobContent` and pass in the `values.myJobName`

```
              <Button
                onClick={()=> {
                          setJobContent({values.myJobName})
                        }}
              />
              Click
              </Button>
```

I also have the following function outside of my `<Formik>` and `<Form>` tags:

```
const setJobContent = (jobName) => {
 // do something 
 // return something
}
```

Unsure if this is possible and if so, would appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want to get only "myJobName" in setJobContent function then you have to pass `setJobContent(values.myJobName)` like this.

Comment: Unfortunately when I do this and console log the result of the parameter, it's null, i.e. `values.myJobName` - could this be because it's a function outside of `Formik` tags?

Comment: Function outside of Formik tags doesn't matter in your case because you are passing `values.myJobName` to setJobContent function so when you click on button you will get value of myJobName in seJobContent function. Make sure you are using `initialValues={{ myJobName: 'ABC' }}` in Formik.

Answer (score 1):

Is this the behavior you wanted?
https://codesandbox.io/live/jpr5fj3

```
export default function App() {

const setJobContent = (jobName) => {
    alert(jobName);
};



return (
  <div className="App">
    <Formik initialValues={{ myJobName: "test" }}>
      {({ values, handleChange }) => (
        <form>
          <input
            type="text"
            name="myJobName"
            onChange={handleChange}
            value={values.myJobName}
           />

          <em>{JSON.stringify(values, null, 2)}</em>
        <button
          type="button"
          onClick={() => setJobContent(values.myJobName)}
        >
          Submit
        </button>
      </form>
    )}
  </Formik>
</div>
);
}`
```